# NSTokenField autocomplete

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, autocomplete, parsing, nstokenfield

I'm creating an application which uses an NSTokenField. I need autocompletion. I'm using an NSURLRequest to request data from `http://stackoverflow.com/filter/tags?_=<timestamp>&limit=6&q=<str_to_autocomplete>&timestamp=<timestamp>`

Where `<timestamp>` is the current timestamp, an `<str_to_autocomplete>` is the string to autocomplete. So, e.g. `http://stackoverflow.com/filter/tags?_=1263657227137&q=lol&limit=6&timestamp=1263657227137`

The response is in this format:

```
javascript|23179
jquery|16936
sql-server|11768
ruby-on-rails|8669
best-practices|7037
ruby|6722
```

(The number is the number of times this tag is used).

I need to give provide the user a list under the NSTokenField with this list of tags, and the user can either select one of the list, or continue typing.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Edit: I'm looking at Mac Dev Center now. Should I use this method: `tokenField:completionsForSubstring:indexOfToken:indexOfSelectedItem:` ?

Comment: I'm slightly confused as to what you're asking. Do you want to display the list of tags in the token field for selection, or do you have an additional control under it for the tags and when selected they will appear in the token field?

Comment: An aditional control under it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be send to the delegate to query an array of strings:

```
tokenField:completionsForSubstring:indexOfToken:indexOfSelectedItem:
```

These strings should then be processed by the `tokenField` in `representedObject` (or not if you need only strings).

Example in your `tokenField` delegate:

```
- (NSArray *)tokenField:(NSTokenField *)tokenField completionsForSubstring:(NSString *)substring indexOfToken:(NSInteger)tokenIndex indexOfSelectedItem:(NSInteger *)selectedIndex
{
    //code to find the tags strings corresponding to substring (the string typed in the token)
    //then put them in an array (returnArray)
    return returnArray;
}
```

The `tokenField` will present the strings completed in a menu as you type. All details are in the doc.